# why does trying to add a line item on order presave redirect to the user page?

Tags: commerce

I have a lot more code than this in the hook_commerce_order_presave() however this

```
if ($show_charge_in_cart == True) {
  $product = commerce_product_load_by_sku("0909990000005");
  $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, $setup_fee_count, $order->order_id);
  commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
  //$order->commerce_line_items['und'][] = array('line_item_id' => $line_item->line_item_id);
  $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
  $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;
}
```

bit is failing and redirecting me to my user page specifically any combination of the last four lines whether I use the last 2 or the third from the end doesn't seem to matter and if I comment out the line_item_save it doesn't do it either.

To get back to the cart view I have to clear the caches (however checking the admin view I can see the setup fee was added to the order), then it will let me load the page once (and it shows the setup fee) continuing or updating the cart causes it to go back to the user page and will not let me back to the cart until I clear the caches again.

(edit)Added Full Code:

```
function edit_commerce_functionality_commerce_order_presave($order) {
  //dsm($order);
  $mouldings_in_order = False;
  if ($order->status == "cart" || $order->status == "checkout_checkout" || $order->status == "checkout_review") {
    foreach ($order->commerce_line_items['und'] as $unloaded_line_item) {
      $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($unloaded_line_item['line_item_id']);
      $product = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product['und'][0]['product_id']);
      if ($product->type == "moulding") {
        $mouldings_in_order = True;
      }
    unset($product);
    unset($line_item);
    }
  }
  if ($mouldings_in_order == True) {
    foreach ($order->commerce_line_items['und'] as $unloaded_line_item) {
      $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($unloaded_line_item['line_item_id']);
      if ($line_item->line_item_label == "0909990000005") {
        commerce_cart_order_product_line_item_delete($order->order_id, $line_item->line_item_id, True);
      }
    }
    unset($line_item);

    $data = Array();
    $setup_fee_count = 0;
    $show_charge_in_cart = False;

    foreach ($order->commerce_line_items['und'] as $unloaded_line_item) {
      $line_item = commerce_line_item_load($unloaded_line_item['line_item_id']);
      $product = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product['und'][0]['product_id']);
      $knumber = $product->field_knife_number['und'][0]['safe_value'];
      $line_item_price = $line_item->commerce_total['und'][0]['amount'] / 100;
      $made_to_order = $product->field_made_to_order['und'][0]['safe_value'];
      if ($made_to_order == "Made To Order usually ships in 2-3 Weeks") {
        $data[] = Array("knumber" => $knumber, "price" => $line_item_price);
      }
    }
    unset($product);
    unset($line_item);

    $master_data = array();

    foreach($data as $value) {
      if(array_key_exists($value['knumber'], $master_data)) {
          $master_data[$value['knumber']] += $value['price'];
      } else {
          $master_data[$value['knumber']] = $value['price'];
      }
    }
    unset($data);

    foreach($master_data as $value) {
      if ($value < 250.00) {
        $setup_fee_count += 1;
        $show_charge_in_cart = True;
      }
    }

    if ($show_charge_in_cart == True) {
      $product = commerce_product_load_by_sku("0909990000005");
      $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, $setup_fee_count, $order->order_id);
      commerce_line_item_save($line_item);
      //$order->commerce_line_items['und'][] = array('line_item_id' => $line_item->line_item_id);
      $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
      $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;
    }
  }
}
```

any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that's performing a redirect, can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I know that but it is sending me to my account page every time I try to update the cart or continue to checkout and then clicking on cart wont let me get back to the cart

Comment: I added the full code for the function to the question

Comment: I don't see any redirects in your updated code which would suggest it's happening in response to a hook being invoked (maybe the new product but I obviously couldn't say from here). Check for custom modules that implement commerce related hooks, and if you can't find any of those check any rules you have enabled